# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'main.profile'. Did you forget to specify values ['username']?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I keep getting this error even though I have a value for username:

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'main.profile'. Did you forget to specify values ['username']?

Here is my code:

```
{% for user in users %}
<a href="{{ url_for('.profile', username=user.username) }}">
{{ user.username }} #This work fine, I don't know why the one in the anchor tag doesn't work.
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Could this be a BUG in werkzeug?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't you be escaping the quotes?

Comment: Which quotes? @0TTT0

Comment: the ones in the anchor tag

Comment: I didn't think it mattered but tried it and it sure didn't.

Comment: Please change the question to be more descriptive of the issue you're having, something like "werkzeug.routing.BuildError blahblah"

Answer (score -2):

you can try this one.you can't assign value to variable in template engine

```html
{% for user in users %}
<a href="{{ url_for('.profile', user.username) }}">
</a>
{% endfor %}
```